# Правильно ли составлена фраза по смыслу и пунктуации?

Tags: пунктуация, грамотная-речь, орфография, запятые, синтаксис

> Миша, проснулся от раздавшегося за окном со стороны дороги, писклявого
> с хрипотцой голоса, который взбудоражил местных собак и откуда то из
> далека стали доноситься тихий вой и лай.

Comment: С таким началом можно запятую ставить после каждого слова.

Comment: Немного не понял вас)

Comment: А зачем у вас запятая после "Миши"?

Comment: Ошибка. Имена выделяются только при обращении. Спасибо!

Comment: Но потом запятых уже не хватает...  Мне кажется, вы неясно представляете грамматику вашего предложения, с лексикой и стилистикой тоже есть проблемы.  Например, взбудораженные собаки не будут лаять тихо, а вой откуда появился?  Очень  сложно построена определительная конструкция для сущ. "голоса".  И в целом не очень понятно, что же там происходит. Попробуйте еще поработать над этим предложением.

Comment: Вой и лай из далека, поэтому и тихо!

Comment: И каким же образом голос (даже не крик) мог взбудоражить собак, находящихся вдалеке?

Comment: Моя собака услышит разговор людей в далеке и начинает заливаться лаем.

Comment: Поздравляю. Тем не менее достоверности во фразе нет, картинка не складывается, и одно исправление пунктуации не сделает её верной по смыслу.

Comment: Наречия пишутся слитно: издалека, вдалеке. Лай, как мне кажется, тихим вообще не бывает, а отдаленный лай  лучше назвать приглушенным. Но главное - у вас неясно прорисовано пространство. Местными называют собак, живущих поблизости, голос тоже раздался под окном, но вы говорите о лае собак да еще и о вое, которые доносятся издалека.  Но местные-то собаки стали бы лаять в первую очередь, об этом тоже надо сказать.

Comment: @She *Имена выделяются только при обращении.* Не-не, это неверно! Вот примеры из Нацкорпуса: **Миша,** в одной руке державший бутыль, заключённую в прутяную изгородь, в другой ― новый вещмешок, снисходительно улыбался. [Виктор Астафьев. Обертон (1995-1996)] **Серега,** глядя на меня, пышущего яростью и молчаливого, немного присмирел, хмель из него понемногу выходил... [Владимир Василиненко...] **Серега,** наш водитель, ворчал на меня за то, что я не предупредила его о последствиях, за то, что не взяла на себя эту священную миссию — варить ему грибы. [Марина Марина...]